# Retrieve Ray Tracer data

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, rendering, source-code

I need to be able to, given a scene in Cycles, extract the values of direct lighting intensity and angle of incidence for every light ray that hits a mesh.
The final goal is to use these values to establish how intense is the light hitting the mesh, and with which angle.

For the intensity I'm aware that I can use the inverse square law, but I was wondering if there was another method.

Unfortunately, I'm not particularly good at searching in the source code of Blender.
Is something like this possible just using for the most part pre existing code, or the only way is for me to implement a rudimental ray tracer to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Baskieri, Welcome to Blender.SE. I have Q&A with a [custom python raytracer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/151045/30849). And [this answer on face illumination](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137776/30849) may already be what you are seeking?

Comment: They will definetly be usefull if I decide to implement my own ray tracer. For now I'm hoping that these kind of datas are already stored somewhere during the rendering process in blender, and that someone will be able to tell me how to retrieve them. However thank you for the response!